# How can I do a where AND where in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, fluent

This is what I currently have:

```
$query->orderBy('id', 'DESC')

        ->where('totalColorless', '!=', 0) // currently removes all of these...
        ->where('totalResidual', '!=', 0) // ...and all of these

        ->get();
```

How can I make it so it removes rows which fulfill both WHERE criteria at the same time?

Comment: Or I'm misunderstanding your question or your query is already doing what you are asking. This is doing `WHERE private != 1 AND totalColorless != 0 AND totalResidual != 0`

Comment: There are columns which have totalColorless = 0 but totalResidual = 1 or vice versa. Basically I'd like to remove rows which are both totalColorless = 0 AND totalResidual = 0 at the same time.

Comment: Err then just do that..  Why can't your query should be something like this `->where('totalColorless', '=', 0)->where('totalResidual', '=', 0)`

Comment: Just `->where('totalColorless', 0)->where('totalResidual', 0)` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with "orWhere":

```
[...]
->where('totalColorless', '!=', 0)
->orWhere('totalResidual', '!=', 0)
[...]
```

Comment: I tried orWhere and oddly it worked correctly. If you change to orWhere I'll choose yours as the answer.

Comment: changed, but you really need to do an `orWhere`?

Comment: It's odd, the orWhere acts the same as an AND in php. Maybe MySQL commands are named oddly?

Comment: i think that you can get the query string with `->getQueryLog()` or `->toSql()` and check it

Answer (score 0):

I think you must put `orderBy()` before `get()` and after `where()`